# Match mobile numbers to people in a list ordered chronologically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-indirect

I have an sorted 'customer' sheet, containing the customer's ID number and their mobile number next to that, from **#1** to **#10**. These customers orders/visits are to be listed in another sheet, in chronological order. I am trying to get the customer's mobile number by simply putting in their ID, and possibly add details once I get it working.

Is there a way that I am able to get the value of a customer's cell, variant on the customer ID number entered?

Logically as a Java developer, I have tried doing `'=(Customers!B(A4))`, but that doesn't seem to work. Basically, I need to set a value to the cell of B(customer ID number) in sheet customer, how would I go about this?

Comment: Check out `VLOOKUP()`

Comment: Or `index` plus `match` which is a little harder to understand but is more flexible and less prone to errors counting columns (or inserting columns)

Comment: I'm looking into both of these options now. How would I use both index and match together? I'm not quite sure of either's functionality so of course I'm going to need to look into them both. Thanks.

Comment: I believe so. I didn't find it sorry, I was unsure as to how to phrase the question. All sorted now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest VLOOKUP, partly because you don't seem to have too many variables:

[image: SO20712634 example]

Note that this will not work if columns A and B are switched over in customer sheet.

Comment: One question though, is there a way to do this if another piece of data was 2 columns away from the Id number?

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks. (And I had to change the B$13 to C$13, but your explanation was great thanks).

Answer (score 1):

You could try combining `INDIRECT`, `ADDRESS`, and `CELL`:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row", reference_cell), column_number))`

So, instead of this:

`'=(Customers!B(A4))`

try this (column B is the 2nd column):

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row", $A4), 2))`